# How to get network interfaces to show up without systemd?

Tags: systemd, network-interface, runit

I'm trying to switch from `systemd` to `runit`. When I boot my computer with `systemd` as PID 1, my wireless card shows up in `/sys/class/net`. But when I boot with `runit-init` as PID 1, the only thing that shows up in `/sys/class/net` is the loopback device.

How do I make the wireless card show up properly?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, all I had to do was load iwlwifi